# How do I migrate the release from one Gitlab repository to another

Tags: gitlab

So I need to migrate my Gitlab repository to a new repository, I did the following:

1. Create a bare bone repostiory

   git clone --bare old_git_repo directory
2. Go into the the newly created clone directory:

   cd directory
3. Pull in Git Large File storage object

   git lfs fetch --all
4. Mirror Push to the new repostory

   git push --mirror new_git_repo
5. Push large file storage objects

   git lfs push --all new_git_repo

This worked pretty well. When I looked at the new repository, I can see all of the branches, and all of the tags. However, I notice that none of the release have migrated. Is there a good way to migrate the release?

Answer (score 0):

So the reason this does not work is because artifacts like Release and issues exists outside of Git and are actually Gitlab artifacts. Because they are gitlab artifacts, they cannot be migrated using git commands. To migrate them, you would need to use gitlab export or migrate.

In my case, the reason I can't do that is because the repository was old and admin couldn't get admin access to grant me permission to export and migrate. The steps proposed in the question does allow what is in git including branches and tags to be move to the new repostory. To get a specific release one can use git clone --branch  to get a particular release.